# Access Denied Django : (1045, "Access denied for user 'darth_vader'@'151.33.241.48' (using password: YES)")

Tags: python, django, backend, django-settings

I am using django 3.0 and using MySQL database for my web application.
My settings.py code is:

```
    DATABASES = {
  'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'thirdihrms',
    'USERNAME': 'admin',
    'PASSWORD': 'xxxxxxxx',
    'HOST': 'database-1.xxxxxxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com',
    'PORT': '3306',
   }
}
```

And instead of connecting to the admin@151.33.241.48 it's getting connected to the darth_vader username.
The darth_vader name is my ubantu machine (Local development environment) home user name.

I see "darth_vader@Rushikesh-HP:~$ " when i open my terminal.

The error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "/home/darth_vader/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 220, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/home/darth_vader/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/darth_vader/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 197, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/home/darth_vader/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/darth_vader/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 233, in get_new_connection
    return Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/home/darth_vader/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 84, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/darth_vader/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 179, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'darth_vader'@'157.33.241.48' (using password: YES)")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/darth_vader/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/darth_vader/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/darth_vader/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/darth_vader/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 366, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/home/darth_vader/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 395, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/home/darth_vader/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 63, in _run_checks
    issues = run_checks(tags=[Tags.database])
  File "/home/darth_vader/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/home/darth_vader/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/database.py", line 10, in check_database_backends
    issues.extend(conn.validation.check(**kwargs))
  File "/home/darth_vader/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/validation.py", line 9, in check
    issues.extend(self._check_sql_mode(**kwargs))
  File "/home/darth_vader/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/validation.py", line 13, in _check_sql_mode
    with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
  File "/home/darth_vader/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/darth_vader/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 260, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "/home/darth_vader/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 236, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/home/darth_vader/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/darth_vader/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 220, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/home/darth_vader/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/darth_vader/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 220, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/home/darth_vader/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/darth_vader/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 197, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/home/darth_vader/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/darth_vader/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 233, in get_new_connection
    return Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/home/darth_vader/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 84, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/darth_vader/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 179, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'darth_vader'@'157.33.241.48' (using password: YES)")
```

So is there any config change or setting change so i can run my application.

Comment: The key is `'USER'`, not `'USERNAME'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *key* to specify the username is [**`'USER'`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-USER), not <s>`'USERNAME'`</s>. As the documentation specifies:

> **`USER`**
>
> Default: `''` (Empty string)
>
> The **username to use** when connecting to the database. Not used with
> SQLite.

You thus should fix this with:

```
DATABASES = {
  'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'thirdihrms',
    'USER': 'admin',  # no USERNAME
    'PASSWORD': 'xxxxxxxx',
    'HOST': 'database-1.xxxxxxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com',
    'PORT': '3306',
   }
}
```